# XMLTABLE Error on a column

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltable

```
SELECT  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NUM_FATT.NUMERO_FATTURA) AS RIGA,  
NUM_FATT.NUMERO_FATTURA,  
POD_ANAG.CODICE_POD,  
DETT_CORRISPETTIVI_POD.*  
FROM XML_TEMP X,  
XMLTABLE('FlussoFattureTrasporto/Fatture'  
         PASSING X.XML_DATI  
         COLUMNS  
           NUMERO_FATTURA VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'FNumeroFattura',  
           NUM_POD XMLTYPE path 'DettaglioPOD',  
           DETTAGLIO_POD XMLTYPE path 'DettaglioPOD/Corrispettivi') NUM_FATT,  
XMLTABLE('/'  
         PASSING NUM_FATT.NUM_POD  
         COLUMNS  
          CODICE_POD VARCHAR2(1000) PATH 'DCodicePod') POD_ANAG,            
XMLTABLE('/'  
         PASSING NUM_FATT.DETTAGLIO_POD  
         COLUMNS  
          ID_CALCOLO VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'DIDCalcolo',  
          COMPONENTE VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'DComponente',  
          PERIODO_COMPETENZA_DA VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'DPeriodoCompetenzaDa',  
          PERIODO_COMPETENZA_A VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'DPeriodoCompetenzaA',  
          QUANTITA NUMBER PATH 'DQuantita',  
          CORRISPETTIVO_UNITARIO NUMBER PATH 'DCorrispettivoUnitario',  
          CODICE_IVA VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'DCodiceIVA',  
          IMPORTO NUMBER PATH 'DImporto') DETT_CORRISPETTIVI_POD  
ORDER BY  
NUM_FATT.NUMERO_FATTURA;
```

I would like to insert in the rowset the column CODICE_POD, but I have the error ORA-19279: XPTY0004 "XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence" ; if I comment the POD_ANAG.CODICE_POD, the query works.

An example file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FlussoFattureTrasporto xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FlussoFatture.xsd">
 <TestataFlusso>
  <TCodiceFlusso>FTR</TCodiceFlusso>
  <TCodiceTipoFattura>C</TCodiceTipoFattura>
  <TNumeroSequenza>1</TNumeroSequenza>
  <TDataEmissioneFattura>02/05/2017</TDataEmissioneFattura>
  <TDataScadenzaFattura>12/06/2017</TDataScadenzaFattura>
  <TRagioneSocialeMittente>AAA</TRagioneSocialeMittente>
  <TPartitaIVAMittente>123456789</TPartitaIVAMittente>
  <TIndirizzoMittente>bbb</TIndirizzoMittente>
  <TCAPMittente>11111</TCAPMittente>
  <TLocalitaMittente>xx</TLocalitaMittente>
  <TProvinciaMittente>yy</TProvinciaMittente>
  <TNazioneMittente>hh</TNazioneMittente>
  <TIBANMittente>234dfg</TIBANMittente>
  <TRagioneSocialeDestinatario>ddd</TRagioneSocialeDestinatario>
  <TPartitaIVADestinatario>123456789</TPartitaIVADestinatario>
  <TIndirizzoDestinatario>sfdh</TIndirizzoDestinatario>
  <TCAPDestinatario>345</TCAPDestinatario>
  <TLocalitaDestinatario>df</TLocalitaDestinatario>
  <TProvinciaDestinatario>df</TProvinciaDestinatario>
  <TNazioneDestinatario>bh</TNazioneDestinatario>
  <TContrattoDispacciamento>shrtf</TContrattoDispacciamento>
 </TestataFlusso>
 <Fatture>
  <FNumeroFattura>444</FNumeroFattura>
  <TestataFattura>
   <FPeriodoCompetenzaDa>04/2017</FPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
   <FPeriodoCompetenzaA>04/2017</FPeriodoCompetenzaA>
   <FTotaleImponibileFattura>35,02</FTotaleImponibileFattura>
   <FTotaleIVAFattura>7,70</FTotaleIVAFattura>
   <FTotaleFattura>42,72</FTotaleFattura>
  </TestataFattura>
  <RiepilogoFattura>
   <RiepilogoValori>
    <RTipologiaContrattuale>Lettera a)</RTipologiaContrattuale>
    <RNumeroPod>2</RNumeroPod>
    <RTotTarDistQtFissa>1,76</RTotTarDistQtFissa>
    <RTotTarDistQtPotenza>9,02</RTotTarDistQtPotenza>
    <RTotTarDistEnAttiva>3,22</RTotTarDistEnAttiva>
    <RTotTarDistEnReattiva>0,00</RTotTarDistEnReattiva>
    <RTotOnGenUltComQtFissa>0,00</RTotOnGenUltComQtFissa>
    <RTotOnGenUltComQtPotenza>0,08</RTotOnGenUltComQtPotenza>
    <RTotOnGenUltComEnAttiva>20,94</RTotOnGenUltComEnAttiva>
    <RTotaleQuotaFissa>1,76</RTotaleQuotaFissa>
    <RTotaleQuotaPotenza>9,10</RTotaleQuotaPotenza>
    <RTotaleEnergiaAttiva>24,16</RTotaleEnergiaAttiva>
    <RTotaleEnergiaReattiva>0,00</RTotaleEnergiaReattiva>
    <RTotaleGenerale>35,02</RTotaleGenerale>
   </RiepilogoValori>
   <RiepilogoIVA>
    <RAliquotaIVA>22%</RAliquotaIVA>
    <RImponibileIVA>35,02</RImponibileIVA>
    <RImportoIVA>7,70</RImportoIVA>
   </RiepilogoIVA>
   <NoteFattura>Note 2</NoteFattura>
  </RiepilogoFattura>
  <DettaglioPOD>
   <DCodicePod>IT001E111</DCodicePod>
   <DatiTecniciCommerciali>
    <DDTTensione>BT</DDTTensione>
    <DDTPotenzaImpegnata>4,50</DDTPotenzaImpegnata>
    <DDTPotenzaDisponibile>5,00</DDTPotenzaDisponibile>
    <DDCTipologiaContrattuale>Lettera a)</DDCTipologiaContrattuale>
    <DDCTariffaDistribuzione>TDR</DDCTariffaDistribuzione>
    <DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>NO</DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>
    <DDCFornituraEnergivora>NO</DDCFornituraEnergivora>
   </DatiTecniciCommerciali>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>111</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/POD</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>17/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,05194521</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>0,88</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>222</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kW</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>17/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DQuantita>4,50</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,05941726</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>4,55</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>333</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kWh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>17/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>1</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>84,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,034242</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>2,88</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>444</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kWh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>17/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>2</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>72,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,065482</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>4,71</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
  </DettaglioPOD>
  <DettaglioPOD>
   <DCodicePod>IT001E222</DCodicePod>
   <DatiTecniciCommerciali>
    <DDTTensione>BT</DDTTensione>
    <DDTPotenzaImpegnata>4,50</DDTPotenzaImpegnata>
    <DDTPotenzaDisponibile>5,00</DDTPotenzaDisponibile>
    <DDCTipologiaContrattuale>Lettera a)</DDCTipologiaContrattuale>
    <DDCTariffaDistribuzione>TDR</DDCTariffaDistribuzione>
    <DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>NO</DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>
    <DDCFornituraEnergivora>NO</DDCFornituraEnergivora>
   </DatiTecniciCommerciali>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>555</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/POD</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>17/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,05194521</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>0,88</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>666</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kW</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>17/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DQuantita>4,50</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,05941726</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>4,55</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>777</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kWh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>17/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>1</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>84,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,034242</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>2,88</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>888</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kWh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>17/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>2</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>209,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,065482</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>13,69</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
  </DettaglioPOD>
 </Fatture>
 <Fatture>
  <FNumeroFattura>999</FNumeroFattura>
  <TestataFattura>
   <FPeriodoCompetenzaDa>04/2017</FPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
   <FPeriodoCompetenzaA>04/2017</FPeriodoCompetenzaA>
   <FTotaleImponibileFattura>17,98</FTotaleImponibileFattura>
   <FTotaleIVAFattura>3,96</FTotaleIVAFattura>
   <FTotaleFattura>21,94</FTotaleFattura>
  </TestataFattura>
  <RiepilogoFattura>
   <RiepilogoValori>
    <RTipologiaContrattuale>Lettera d)</RTipologiaContrattuale>
    <RNumeroPod>1</RNumeroPod>
    <RTotTarDistQtFissa>1,10</RTotTarDistQtFissa>
    <RTotTarDistQtPotenza>3,98</RTotTarDistQtPotenza>
    <RTotTarDistEnAttiva>0,68</RTotTarDistEnAttiva>
    <RTotTarDistEnReattiva>0,00</RTotTarDistEnReattiva>
    <RTotOnGenUltComQtFissa>6,36</RTotOnGenUltComQtFissa>
    <RTotOnGenUltComQtPotenza>0,00</RTotOnGenUltComQtPotenza>
    <RTotOnGenUltComEnAttiva>5,86</RTotOnGenUltComEnAttiva>
    <RTotaleQuotaFissa>7,46</RTotaleQuotaFissa>
    <RTotaleQuotaPotenza>3,98</RTotaleQuotaPotenza>
    <RTotaleEnergiaAttiva>6,54</RTotaleEnergiaAttiva>
    <RTotaleEnergiaReattiva>0,00</RTotaleEnergiaReattiva>
    <RTotaleGenerale>17,98</RTotaleGenerale>
   </RiepilogoValori>
   <RiepilogoIVA>
    <RAliquotaIVA>22%</RAliquotaIVA>
    <RImponibileIVA>17,98</RImponibileIVA>
    <RImportoIVA>3,96</RImportoIVA>
   </RiepilogoIVA>
   <NoteFattura>note1</NoteFattura>
  </RiepilogoFattura>
  <DettaglioPOD>
   <DCodicePod>IT001E333</DCodicePod>
   <DatiTecniciCommerciali>
    <DDTTensione>BT</DDTTensione>
    <DDTPotenzaImpegnata>3,00</DDTPotenzaImpegnata>
    <DDTPotenzaDisponibile>3,30</DDTPotenzaDisponibile>
    <DDCTipologiaContrattuale>Lettera d)</DDCTipologiaContrattuale>
    <DDCTariffaDistribuzione>BTA2</DDCTariffaDistribuzione>
    <DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>NO</DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>
    <DDCFornituraEnergivora>NO</DDCFornituraEnergivora>
   </DatiTecniciCommerciali>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>999</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/POD</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>17/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,4391126</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>7,46</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>1111</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kW</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>17/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DQuantita>3,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,0780337</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>3,98</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>2222</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kWh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>17/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>1</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>87,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,075182</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>6,54</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
  </DettaglioPOD>
 </Fatture>
 <Fatture>
  <FNumeroFattura>888</FNumeroFattura>
  <TestataFattura>
   <FPeriodoCompetenzaDa>04/2017</FPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
   <FPeriodoCompetenzaA>04/2017</FPeriodoCompetenzaA>
   <FTotaleImponibileFattura>65,44</FTotaleImponibileFattura>
   <FTotaleIVAFattura>14,40</FTotaleIVAFattura>
   <FTotaleFattura>79,84</FTotaleFattura>
  </TestataFattura>
  <RiepilogoFattura>
   <RiepilogoValori>
    <RTipologiaContrattuale>Lettera d)</RTipologiaContrattuale>
    <RNumeroPod>1</RNumeroPod>
    <RTotTarDistQtFissa>1,96</RTotTarDistQtFissa>
    <RTotTarDistQtPotenza>7,12</RTotTarDistQtPotenza>
    <RTotTarDistEnAttiva>4,67</RTotTarDistEnAttiva>
    <RTotTarDistEnReattiva>0,00</RTotTarDistEnReattiva>
    <RTotOnGenUltComQtFissa>11,40</RTotOnGenUltComQtFissa>
    <RTotOnGenUltComQtPotenza>0,00</RTotOnGenUltComQtPotenza>
    <RTotOnGenUltComEnAttiva>40,29</RTotOnGenUltComEnAttiva>
    <RTotaleQuotaFissa>13,36</RTotaleQuotaFissa>
    <RTotaleQuotaPotenza>7,12</RTotaleQuotaPotenza>
    <RTotaleEnergiaAttiva>44,96</RTotaleEnergiaAttiva>
    <RTotaleEnergiaReattiva>0,00</RTotaleEnergiaReattiva>
    <RTotaleGenerale>65,44</RTotaleGenerale>
   </RiepilogoValori>
   <RiepilogoIVA>
    <RAliquotaIVA>22%</RAliquotaIVA>
    <RImponibileIVA>65,44</RImponibileIVA>
    <RImportoIVA>14,40</RImportoIVA>
   </RiepilogoIVA>
   <NoteFattura>note3</NoteFattura>
  </RiepilogoFattura>
  <DettaglioPOD>
   <DCodicePod>IT001E444</DCodicePod>
   <DatiTecniciCommerciali>
    <DDTTensione>BT</DDTTensione>
    <DDTPotenzaImpegnata>3,00</DDTPotenzaImpegnata>
    <DDTPotenzaDisponibile>3,30</DDTPotenzaDisponibile>
    <DDCTipologiaContrattuale>Lettera d)</DDCTipologiaContrattuale>
    <DDCTariffaDistribuzione>BTA2</DDCTariffaDistribuzione>
    <DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>NO</DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>
    <DDCFornituraEnergivora>NO</DDCFornituraEnergivora>
   </DatiTecniciCommerciali>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>3333</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/POD</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>13,3564</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>13,36</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>4444</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kW</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DQuantita>3,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>2,3735</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>7,12</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>5555</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kWh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>1</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>598,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,075182</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>44,96</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
  </DettaglioPOD>
 </Fatture>
 <Fatture>
  <FNumeroFattura>777</FNumeroFattura>
  <TestataFattura>
   <FPeriodoCompetenzaDa>04/2017</FPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
   <FPeriodoCompetenzaA>04/2017</FPeriodoCompetenzaA>
   <FTotaleImponibileFattura>98,74</FTotaleImponibileFattura>
   <FTotaleIVAFattura>21,72</FTotaleIVAFattura>
   <FTotaleFattura>120,46</FTotaleFattura>
  </TestataFattura>
  <RiepilogoFattura>
   <RiepilogoValori>
    <RTipologiaContrattuale>Lettera d)</RTipologiaContrattuale>
    <RNumeroPod>1</RNumeroPod>
    <RTotTarDistQtFissa>1,96</RTotTarDistQtFissa>
    <RTotTarDistQtPotenza>15,04</RTotTarDistQtPotenza>
    <RTotTarDistEnAttiva>7,64</RTotTarDistEnAttiva>
    <RTotTarDistEnReattiva>2,15</RTotTarDistEnReattiva>
    <RTotOnGenUltComQtFissa>10,60</RTotOnGenUltComQtFissa>
    <RTotOnGenUltComQtPotenza>0,00</RTotOnGenUltComQtPotenza>
    <RTotOnGenUltComEnAttiva>61,35</RTotOnGenUltComEnAttiva>
    <RTotaleQuotaFissa>12,56</RTotaleQuotaFissa>
    <RTotaleQuotaPotenza>15,04</RTotaleQuotaPotenza>
    <RTotaleEnergiaAttiva>68,99</RTotaleEnergiaAttiva>
    <RTotaleEnergiaReattiva>2,15</RTotaleEnergiaReattiva>
    <RTotaleGenerale>98,74</RTotaleGenerale>
   </RiepilogoValori>
   <RiepilogoIVA>
    <RAliquotaIVA>22%</RAliquotaIVA>
    <RImponibileIVA>98,74</RImponibileIVA>
    <RImportoIVA>21,72</RImportoIVA>
   </RiepilogoIVA>
   <NoteFattura>note 10</NoteFattura>
  </RiepilogoFattura>
  <DettaglioPOD>
   <DCodicePod>IT001E555</DCodicePod>
   <DatiTecniciCommerciali>
    <DDTTensione>BT</DDTTensione>
    <DDTPotenzaImpegnata>6,00</DDTPotenzaImpegnata>
    <DDTPotenzaDisponibile>100,00</DDTPotenzaDisponibile>
    <DDCTipologiaContrattuale>Lettera d)</DDCTipologiaContrattuale>
    <DDCTariffaDistribuzione>BTA6</DDCTariffaDistribuzione>
    <DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>NO</DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>
    <DDCFornituraEnergivora>NO</DDCFornituraEnergivora>
   </DatiTecniciCommerciali>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>6666</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/POD</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>12,5573</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>12,56</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>7777</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kW</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DQuantita>6,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>2,5061</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>15,04</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>8888</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kWh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>1</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>980,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,070402</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>68,99</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>9999</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kvarh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>33%-75%</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>108,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,00704</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>0,76</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>11111</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kvarh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>33%-75%</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>101,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,00704</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>0,71</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>222222</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kvarh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>75%-100%</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>28,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,00905</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>0,25</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>333333</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kvarh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>75%-100%</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>47,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,00905</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>0,43</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
  </DettaglioPOD>
 </Fatture>
 <Fatture>
  <FNumeroFattura>333</FNumeroFattura>
  <TestataFattura>
   <FPeriodoCompetenzaDa>04/2017</FPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
   <FPeriodoCompetenzaA>04/2017</FPeriodoCompetenzaA>
   <FTotaleImponibileFattura>41,07</FTotaleImponibileFattura>
   <FTotaleIVAFattura>9,04</FTotaleIVAFattura>
   <FTotaleFattura>50,11</FTotaleFattura>
  </TestataFattura>
  <RiepilogoFattura>
   <RiepilogoValori>
    <RTipologiaContrattuale>Lettera d)</RTipologiaContrattuale>
    <RNumeroPod>1</RNumeroPod>
    <RTotTarDistQtFissa>1,96</RTotTarDistQtFissa>
    <RTotTarDistQtPotenza>15,83</RTotTarDistQtPotenza>
    <RTotTarDistEnAttiva>1,24</RTotTarDistEnAttiva>
    <RTotTarDistEnReattiva>0,00</RTotTarDistEnReattiva>
    <RTotOnGenUltComQtFissa>11,40</RTotOnGenUltComQtFissa>
    <RTotOnGenUltComQtPotenza>0,00</RTotOnGenUltComQtPotenza>
    <RTotOnGenUltComEnAttiva>10,64</RTotOnGenUltComEnAttiva>
    <RTotaleQuotaFissa>13,36</RTotaleQuotaFissa>
    <RTotaleQuotaPotenza>15,83</RTotaleQuotaPotenza>
    <RTotaleEnergiaAttiva>11,88</RTotaleEnergiaAttiva>
    <RTotaleEnergiaReattiva>0,00</RTotaleEnergiaReattiva>
    <RTotaleGenerale>41,07</RTotaleGenerale>
   </RiepilogoValori>
   <RiepilogoIVA>
    <RAliquotaIVA>22%</RAliquotaIVA>
    <RImponibileIVA>41,07</RImponibileIVA>
    <RImportoIVA>9,04</RImportoIVA>
   </RiepilogoIVA>
   <NoteFattura>note 11</NoteFattura>
  </RiepilogoFattura>
  <DettaglioPOD>
   <DCodicePod>IT001E666</DCodicePod>
   <DatiTecniciCommerciali>
    <DDTTensione>BT</DDTTensione>
    <DDTPotenzaImpegnata>6,00</DDTPotenzaImpegnata>
    <DDTPotenzaDisponibile>6,60</DDTPotenzaDisponibile>
    <DDCTipologiaContrattuale>Lettera d)</DDCTipologiaContrattuale>
    <DDCTariffaDistribuzione>BTA3</DDCTariffaDistribuzione>
    <DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>NO</DDCProduttoriPuriPerizia>
    <DDCFornituraEnergivora>NO</DDCFornituraEnergivora>
   </DatiTecniciCommerciali>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>444444</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/POD</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>13,3564</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>13,36</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>555555</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kW</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DQuantita>6,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>2,6387</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>15,83</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
   <Corrispettivi>
    <DIDCalcolo>666666</DIDCalcolo>
    <DComponente>€/kWh</DComponente>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>01/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaDa>
    <DPeriodoCompetenzaA>30/04/2017</DPeriodoCompetenzaA>
    <DScaglione>1</DScaglione>
    <DQuantita>158,00</DQuantita>
    <DCorrispettivoUnitario>0,075182</DCorrispettivoUnitario>
    <DCodiceIVA>ORD</DCodiceIVA>
    <DImporto>11,88</DImporto>
   </Corrispettivi>
  </DettaglioPOD>
 </Fatture>
</FlussoFattureTrasporto>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small changes. And your last xmltable can cause a problem during converting to number.  In your data number format is 99,99. Your session can use US format with "." separator.

If exception appears  you have to change NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS to ',.' `<decimal_separator><group_separator>`

`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS =',.';`

```
SELECT  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NUM_FATT.NUMERO_FATTURA) AS RIGA,  
NUM_FATT.NUMERO_FATTURA,  
POD_ANAG.CODICE_POD,  
DETT_CORRISPETTIVI_POD.* 
FROM XML_TEMP X,  
XMLTABLE('FlussoFattureTrasporto/Fatture'  
         PASSING X.XML_DATI
         COLUMNS  
           NUMERO_FATTURA VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'FNumeroFattura',  
           NUM_POD XMLTYPE path 'DettaglioPOD',  
           DETTAGLIO_POD XMLTYPE path 'DettaglioPOD/Corrispettivi') NUM_FATT,  
XMLTABLE('/DettaglioPOD'  
         PASSING NUM_FATT.NUM_POD  
         COLUMNS  
          CODICE_POD VARCHAR2(1000) PATH 'DCodicePod') POD_ANAG,            
XMLTABLE('/Corrispettivi'  
         PASSING NUM_FATT.DETTAGLIO_POD  
         COLUMNS  
          ID_CALCOLO VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'DIDCalcolo',  
          COMPONENTE VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'DComponente',  
          PERIODO_COMPETENZA_DA VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'DPeriodoCompetenzaDa',  
          PERIODO_COMPETENZA_A VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'DPeriodoCompetenzaA',  
          QUANTITA number  PATH 'DQuantita',  
          CORRISPETTIVO_UNITARIO number  PATH 'DCorrispettivoUnitario',  
          CODICE_IVA VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'DCodiceIVA',  
          IMPORTO number PATH 'DImporto') DETT_CORRISPETTIVI_POD
```